# Named argument in actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, syntax

If I have a function like:

```
        public function defaultValues(first = 1,second =2,third = 3)
        {
            trace(first);
            trace(second);
            trace(third);
        }
```

How can I call this function by only passing in a value for second = 20 ?

Comment: in c# e.g. you can do defaultValues(second:20); Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ActionScript3 does not support named parameters.**  If you really want this behavior, you can use an associative array... but I don't recommend it unless you really want to be dynamic :

```
public function defaultValues(params:Object)
{
    var first = "first" in params ? params.first : 1;
    var second = "second" in params ? params.second : 2;
    var third = params.third ? params.third : 3;

    trace(first);
    trace(second);
    trace(third);
}
```

Then, you can call it:

```
defaultValues({second: 99});
```

Comment: haha ... good one :) But magic string typing is not my thing :)

Comment: That is not magic string typing... it is duck typing.  If you don't like using magic strings, you can just ask for the param.  Seem my modifications.  Again, this assumes dynamic typing for these parameters.

Comment: I meant "typing magic strings" :) because there is no way to keep someone from typing <code>defaultValues({seocnd: 99});</code> and the error will never get checked. Its magic because without looking at the code of the function the consumer will have no idea about what to pass in.

Comment: Again, it is how dynamic programming works... JavaScript does it all the time.  I suspect what you want is NOT dynamic typing... but still, there is nothing wrong with this approach if what you are trying to achieve is dynamic.  That is all...

Comment: Yes I understand. That is why I don't like dynamic typing :)

Comment: it's only magic typing because the parameter is an `Object`. There's no reason why you can't make a custom class with the named parameters there. It's a PITA, but it'll work :)

Answer (score 2):

You should call:

```
defaultValues(1, 20);
```

BTW it is **extremely bad** practice not to use strict typing in ActionScript. Maybe you have Javascript or ActionScript 2 background but it can't be excuse. So your method should looks like:

```
    public function defaultValues(first:int = 1,second:int =2,third:int = 3) : void
    {
        trace(first);
        trace(second);
        trace(third);
    }
```

Comment: I have c# background and noticed the compiler warning anyway :) So there is no built in syntax for this like c#? Arguments always need to be positional?

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.  AS3 does not support named arguments/parameters.  You can use associative arrays... if you want... but it is ugly.

Comment: Right. You can pass the same values as default before passing some other value like in the code I've provided.

Comment: To add to @Constantiner's comment about strict typing... you can use strict typing and still be dynamic (if that is your goal) by declaring that it is dynamic: `public function defaultValues(first:*, second:*, third:*):void {}`

Comment: A couple more comments... calling `defaultValues(1,20)` isn't ideal either... because if the function definition for `defaultValues` changes the default value of `first`, then your code doesn't get notified.  There is no good solution for what you want to accomplish IMO.  AS3 should implement named parameters for this very reason.  Point #2: You should also declare the return type of your function: `public function foo():void`.

Comment: @Brian Genisio: Oh yes I've missed absence of return statement :) What about notice that `defaultValues(1, 20)` isn't ideal solution I 100% agree. But it is the only solution at the moment :( ActionScript needs a lot of improvements but I think we won't see them next 3 years or so :(

Comment: @Constantiner: Agreed on all accounts.

Comment: Voting you up, by the way... we can't type this much and not get any cred points... :)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a parameter class for only that function.
Although it is a bit of an overkill, it will give you optional parameters which are strictly typed. It does however require a lot more coding.

```
class DefaultValuesParams {
    public var first:int = 1;
    public var second:int = 2;
    public var third:int = 3;
}

var optionalArgs:DefaultValueParams = new DefaultValueParams();
optinalArgs.second = 20;
defaultValues(optionalArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to overload the method with only one parameter and from the overloaded method call the 3 param method with default values for first and third.

Comment: That would work. But actually this is a syntax question not a workaround question. Is the syntax possible?

Comment: ActionScript doesn't support methods overloading.

Comment: @Constantiner true. I just verified. Thanks.